# Update Supporting Files from Web Server

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, webserver, updates

I am writing an IPhone application in witch I downloaded files and photos locally  in the `Supporting Files` folder ( in the right panel of xcode ),  these files are downloaded also in a web server, what I want is that if the application detect that these files are updated in the web server , it replace them with the new content in the `Supporting Files` I used

```
NSArray* pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
documentsDirectory = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* localFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"];
[data writeToFile:localFile options:NSDataWritingAtomic  error:&error];
```

the code works well but the problem is that it replaces content of files in
`Library/Application Support` folder and not the `Supporting Files`  so when I do :

```
NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *TextURL = [thisBundle pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt"];
NSURL *instructionsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:TextURL];
NSString *TextString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:instructionsURL];
mayText.text = TextString;
```

the old content is displayed and not the updated one
How can I change my code to replace files in Supporting files directory every time Application Support files are changed ? And what is the difference between these two folders? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. iOS Apps on the device are signed, changing the bundle's content would break that signing. And as all files that are managed by Xcode and added to a target go to the bundle, they must not be changed.

Instead download the files to a sandbox directory, such as Documents and access it there.

Also note that `Supporting Files` iin Xcode is not a directory but a group. It juste groups it content inside the Xcode project but does not organize the files in a directory on file system level.

Comment: Thank you very much for ansewering, I want to ask you please what is better to save those files in Documents by using `NSDocumentationDirectory`or in Supporting Files by : `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` ?